# The collision log is displayed only for the original obstacle and not for the duplicates

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

This is my first game attempt and I'm trying to create a game where my player (a box) stops whenever it collides with an obstacle. However, the log for the collision is only displayed when the player collides with the original obstacle, while no message is displayed for colliding with any other obstacles.
Here's my code:

```
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement; //Reference to player movement script

    //This function will run when collision occurs, the info collision is stored in collisionInfo
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.gameObject.name == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false; //Stop the player from moving
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its obvious that your  **OnCollisionEnter** only works that is collided with other object with name of  **"Obstacle"**. when you duplicate an object the name changes like **Obstacle(1)**.

if you want it work, you have to rename new objects as first one. right solution for this problem is tags. tags are shared names for group of objects.

instead of `collisionInfo.gameObject.name` use `collisionInfo.gameObject.tag` thenin up right side of you screen find tags section and define new tag named **Obstacle** and set this tag to all of your obstacles. when you duplicate and object, new one still has same **tag**.

Comment: Don't forget to use `CompareTag()` rather than `.tag ==` :)

Comment: @DMGregory what? does it really matter?

Comment: It does. `.tag ==` can allocate, but `CompareTag()` does not. Though if we care about efficiency, discriminating object types by layer rather than tag can be even faster. :)

Comment: It works, thank you very much....